# Validate strings using regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I need a bit of help.

I'm pretty new to Python (I use version 3.0 bundled with Anaconda) and I want to use regex to validate/return a list of only valid numbers that match a criteria (say \d{11} for 11 digits). I'm getting the list using Pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['phoneNumber','count'], data=[
    ['08034303939',11],
    ['08034382919',11],
    ['0802329292',10],
    ['09039292921',11]])
```

When I return all the items using

```
for row in df.iterrows(): # dataframe.iterrows() returns tuple
    print(row[1][0])
```

it returns all items without regex validation, but when I try to validate with this

```
for row in df.iterrows(): # dataframe.iterrows() returns tuple
    print(re.compile(r"\d{11}").search(row[1][0]).group())
```

it returns an Attribute error (since the returned value for non-matching values is None.

How can I work around this, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to validate, you can use [`str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and convert to a boolean mask using [`df.astype(bool)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
x = df['phoneNumber'].str.match(r'\d{11}').astype(bool)
x

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: phoneNumber, dtype: bool
```

You can use boolean indexing to return only rows with valid phone numbers.

```
df[x]

   phoneNumber  count
0  08034303939     11
1  08034382919     11
3  09039292921     11
```